# How to link ElastiCache cluster to Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elasticache

I am using Elastic Beanstalk and Amazon RDS. Now I want to cache this RDS.

According to [this documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.ElastiCache.html), I just have to create an ElastiCache cluster and give it access for the security group of the Elastic Beanstalk cluster. I have done that. But I am not sure, whether this Redis cache cluster is caching the Beanstalk's RDS. How can I link the two and also ensure that they are indeed linked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ElastiCache doesn't (automatically) cache RDS. You can implement code that does that yourself but that's not what it does.

ElastiCache provides you with Memcached or Redis in-memory databases as a service. You have to write to and read from the database yourself